# Opera crashes every time I open it

Tags: browser, crash, opera

This started to happen suddenly, without me doing anything. I didn't browse a specific site, just had 3 tabs open with sites I usually visit. And I get a crash report:

> A problem has occurred, forcing Opera to close. To help us avoid
>   similar problems in the future, please send an error report below

If I choose "Full restart" from that dialog, it restarts and crashes again immediately. The same thing happens if I choose "minimal restart".

What could be the problem?

I guess uninstalling and reinstalling would fix it, but I don't want to loose current settings, emails, cookies etc.

Comment: What exact Opera version do you use? (type `opera:about`). Secondly we need to know if you installed your Opera in portable or normal mode to give you advices how to [save your profile](http://my.opera.com/operawiki/forums/topic.dml?id=1132442)

Comment: I can't type that because Opera won't start, but I remember that it upgraded automatically yesterday so I guess it's the latest version. I installed it in normal mode from what I remember (I just clicked next next etc)

Comment: So I copied the folders mentioned in that link, uninstalled Opera, reinstalled it and it opened without errors. Then closed it, copied back the old folders and now it crashes again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you try to reinstall, you should try to start with a fresh profile and copy your old data piece by piece back

1. Cut & paste your profile to your desktop. Your profile is stored under these 2 locations

   - C:\Users\USERNAME\Appdata\Roaming\Opera\Opera\
   - C:\Users\USERNAME\Appdata\Local\Opera\Opera\
2. Start Opera. It should start normally.
3. Look back at these 2 locations. You will notice, that Opera already has recreated some files there
4. Copy the files piece by piece back and do a test by starting Opera if everything is still ok after every single file restore. Do **not** copy the whole folders back.

Safe files & folder to copy back are

- bookmarks.adr
- contacts.adr
- cookies4.dat & download.dat & global_history.dat
- search.ini
- speeddial.ini
- urlfilter.ini
- wand.dat
- (folder)keyboard
- (folder) menu
- (folder) mouse
- (folder) sessions
- (folder) toolbar

The critical files are

- (folder) mail
- (folder) userscripts
- (folder) widgets
- operaprefs.ini
  This is the key file. It stores many settings and a fresh one solves most problems.
  But this also resets many custom settings so you have to set them again.

Comment: so I copied mail, bookmarks, contacts, cookies, speeddial, wand, and operaprefs. And it starts normally now

Answer (score 4):

According to the Opera Forums, many people experienced sudden crashes when Opera upgraded to version 12.13.

The problem seemed like it originated from the Widgets folder. Renaming or deleting the Widgets folder then opening opera again has worked for a lot of people. More info [from the opera forums](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1613752&abc=&page=1&skip=0&show=&perscreen=50).

Specific post that helped myself and others:

1. Close opera
2. Rename/remove folder *Widgets* (`\Documents and Settings\<user_name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Opera\Opera\`)
3. Run opera
4. Close opera
5. Rename/remove back folder *Widgets*
6. Run opera

After the official forums became abuzz with the crashing reports the Opera team officially rolled back the current version for download to 12.12 and that's what some people are installing fresh. I'm still running 12.13 after I renamed my widgets folder.

Answer (score 1):

Opera v12.13 crashes whenever it auto-checks or manually checks for updates of two or more extensions at the same time. This will also prevent you from auto-updating to the version where this issue is now fixed: v12.14, if you have two or more extensions. Make sure you manually [update to the latest version of Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/) to fix this.

From the [Opera v12.14 release notes](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1214/) (release date: 2013-02-05):

> #### Fixes and Stability Enhancements since Opera 12.13
>
> - Update addresses a re-occuring crash, allowing users to update two or more extensions at one time.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem previously with 12.13, which was solved by the 12.14 update, BUT I just had the problem again today.  I tried 12.15 RC2 but it still crashed immediately on startup as well.  No crash logging either, just an instant crash.

The problem turned out to be hardware acceleration turned on in **operaprefs.ini**, and for some reason updating my nVidia driver to a newer version broke that.  So, setting hardware acceleration to 0 fixed the problem:

```
; File: %AppData%\Opera\Opera x64\operaprefs.ini
Enable Hardware Acceleration=0
```

I thought I'd add this answer for people who may have this problem and it isn't solved by the above method or an update.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking autoupdate.opera.com in hosts or firewall also prevents updating.

Original configuration (no problem): SSL 3: ON TLS 1: ON TLS 1.1: OFF TLS 1.2: OFF

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very computer savvy. After importing bookmarks from Chrome to Opera, every time I went to bookmarks in the drop down menu from the Opera logo
top-left on my computer screen, Opera would crash immediately. The Opera window went to a black screen for a second and then back to the Opera screen.

This helped to stop the above progression:

Immediately after the crash, I restart Opera as soon as possible. Then I put my cursor on the word bookmark from the drop-down menu. It did not crash and I left it there a short time. My bookmarks bar came back, and then the function from bookmarks I wanted was usable.

This was not a permanent fix, but helped.

Comment: This sounds like coincidence rather than a reliably reproducible solution.